# Next running inside docker is not seeing files changed on the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, next.js

I'm trying to run Next.js in dev mode inside of docker. I'd like make changes on my host machine and have Next.js rebuild the app running inside of docker. The problem is that it will do the initial build but not perform any rebuilds.

`Dockerfile.dev`

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build
```

`docker-compose.dev.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - /usr/src/app/.next
```

Note: 3001 is the port it's running on. That's not a mistake.

What am I missing?

### Edit

I'm seeing recommendations for `npm run watch` but the [Next documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started#manual-setup) specifies `dev`, `build`, `start` scripts. Their specific naming is not important but `dev` or the `next` command is how you watch for changes and rebuild.

Comment: Can you stop the Docker version of the process, and just `npm run watch` using your host's Node installation?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I can run locally but I want to run this in docker.